# Datatables not showing my data but after applying filter

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, datatables

I am populating a table via Ajax JSON with datatables, this is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.ajax({
    url: "../WebService.asmx/LoadUsers",
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    //content: 'json',  lo mismo que arriba
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {

        var datos = JSON.parse(data.d);

        //  METODO  JQUERY DATATABLES  Documentación
        $('#tblUsers').DataTable({
            data: datos,
            columns: [
                { 'data': 'id' },
                { 'data': 'username' },
                { 'data': 'password' },
                { 'data': 'dregistered' },
                {
                    'data': null,
                    'defaultContent': "<img src='../assets/img/delete.png' id='btnDel' style='width: 22px; cursor:pointer;' />"
                }
                //
            ],
            responsive: true
        });
        /*DataTables instantiation.*/
        /*$("#tblUsers").DataTable();*/
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Fail!');
    }
});
});
```

Html table:

```
<table id="tblUsers" class="table table-bordered nowrap" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th>Contraseña</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th>Contraseña</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

[My table after loading html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIh0F.png)
Is not showing data, it seems like not rendering at first, but after applying column filter or changing entries, the data is showing:
[Filtering by entries number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtCLi.png)

[Filtering by column order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGdl5.png)

Am I missing something?

Comment: PLEASE, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), **NOT** code screenshots. Thanks ;)

Comment: Some suggestions to increase your chances of getting a good answer: (1) please don't provide screenshots of code - provide the code itself, formatted appropriately; (2) try to provide enough information so that the problem can be reproduced - for example, consider showing a sample of the JSON you are receiving, the logic in your `error` function, and so on. Background [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I notice that you are creating your DataTable twice - you should only need to create & initialize it once. Also, have you considered re-arranging your approach to use DataTables' built-in support for [Ajax-sourced data](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/)? You can certainly use jQuery Ajax - but it can sometimes be simpler to use the DataTables ajax option instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably that you are trying to set 5 columns of data (even if the 5th one has `data: null`) but you have only 4 columns in your HTML `<table>`.

If you look at your *console*, probably there should be some error like `Cannot read property 'style' of undefined` or similar.
So, the loading of the data inside the table is interrupted by the error.

Change your HTML to this (adding an extra `<th></th>`) and it should go fine:

```
<table id="tblUsers" class="table table-bordered nowrap" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>Contraseña</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>Contraseña</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes it was that, I was forgetting that lol.  Thank you.